# How to nest while loops in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to make a simple `*` pyramid using while loops but it stops at the first five `*`. I can't figure out why.

This is my code:

```
x = 5
y = 0

while x > 0
  while y < x
    print "*"
    y +=1
  end   

  x -= 1

end
```

Comment: Can you paste the final output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never reset `y` or print a new line

```
x = 5
y = 0

while x > 0
    while y < x
        print "*"
        y +=1
    end 
    print "\n"
    y = 0

    x -= 1

end
```

Output

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

---

**That is bad Ruby tho**

This is a much more idiomatic solution

```
5.downto(1) do |x|
  1.upto(x) do |y|
    print "*"
  end
  print "\n"
end
```

Output

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

I don't know what the final shape of "pyramid" you're looking for, but you can likely adapt the technique above to get the desired output

Comment: You might explain why `downto` and `upto` with blocks are preferred over using `while` blocks.